# SQL2012 - Send backup to client via SQL Job

Tags: sql-server, backup, jobs

Something I thought would be fairly easy..

We host a website for a client. They would like us to send them a database backup monthly. They have Email limits that make sending via EMail not viable. They don't have an FTP site.

I'm trying to come up with a fairly simple, reliable way to (from a scheduled SQL job) copy a backup file to a (free) cloud account like GoogleDrive or OneDrive or ?? that the client can easily access.

No problem creating a SQL job for the backup, scheduling it, etc. the problem is how to then copy the file to an internet destination with minimum hassle. The jobs run under the default SQL Service account.

I'm open to suggestions..?

Comment: Do you have a local webserver/ftp server?  Copy it there for them to download from?

Comment: Although I wouldn't advise using a cloud account, if that does work for you... why not just point the backup job to a Google Drive/DropBox/etc. folder on the server and let it automatically sync?

Comment: Copying data to google drive, I am not sure how safe that would be. I were you I would `take backup on tape and FEDEX the tape`. This is much more secured way.

Comment: What I don't have is admin access to the server, so I don't think I have any way of mapping a cloud drive (since I'm not logged in to the server). If there was a command line way to map a google drive or OneDrive as part of a powershell script I could probably handle that (and I'm open to suggestions if it is possible)..

Comment: As far as security of the backup, this is not HIPAA or critical data of any sort. If someone wants it enough to steal it - oh well. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all the various security concerns are met; I would use SQL Agent to kick off a PowerShell Step that would move the file for you.  Depending on where you end up pushing the file to this can be easier or harder.

Depending on what version of SQL you are using, you also have the option of backing up directly to Azure Blob storage, builtin. More details here [Backup and Restore with Azure Blob Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919148.aspx)

Comment: We are using SQL2012 for the moment although 2014 is imminent. Problem with azure is that we have another recurring expense which probably would be turned down. PITA, but such is life in my world.

Comment: I think Google Drive has an agent that will automatically keep files that are local in sync with files on Google Drive.  But you start getting some security concerns there.  Maybe another server that shares the sync location with the SQL Server that also runs the google drive client?